# Uncheck SelectAll Checkbox if unselect listview checkbox

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I have a custom listview with checkbox. In main layout there is "Select All" check box. If I select the "Select All" checkbox then all checkboxes gets selected. What I want is when I unselect any one of the listview checkbox, the "Select All" checkbox must get unselected too. I tried as shown [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/vus520/archive/2011/02/27/2561875.html) but its not working. If I unselect any listview checkbox all listview checkboxes gets unselected.

```html
public class ContactsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<Contacts> objects;
    CheckBox _selectall;

    ContactsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contacts> products, CheckBox selectall) {
        ctx = context;
        objects = products;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        _selectall=selectall;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
        }
        //final Contacts p = getProduct(position);
        Contacts contacts = objects.get(position);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName)).setText(contacts.getName());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMobile)).setText(contacts.getMobile());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail)).setText(contacts.getEmail());

        final CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);

        cbBuy.setTag(position);
        cbBuy.setChecked(contacts.box);
        if(_selectall.isChecked()){
            _selectall.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            _selectall.setChecked(false);
        }

        cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;

                if(_selectall.isChecked()){
                    _selectall.setChecked(true);
                }else{
                    _selectall.setChecked(false);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        _selectall.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {


                if(_selectall.isChecked()){
                    for(int i=0; i<objects.size();i++){
                        getProduct(i).box = true;
                        cbBuy.setTag(i);
                        cbBuy.setChecked(objects.get(i).box);
                    }

                }else{
                    for(int i=0; i<objects.size();i++){
                        getProduct(i).box = false;
                        cbBuy.setTag(i);
                        cbBuy.setChecked(objects.get(i).box);
                    }
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
        return view;
    }
    Contacts getProduct(int position) {
        return ((Contacts) getItem(position));
    }



    ArrayList<Contacts> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Contacts> box = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
        for (Contacts p : objects) {
            if (p.box)
                box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }


}
```

Comment: Check this http://www.cnblogs.com/vus520/archive/2011/02/27/2561875.html

Answer (score 1):

On checkedChangedListener check total checked items. If it's equal to your total item then selectAll checkbox will true otherwise false. Detail example is [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-checkall-and-uncheckall-for-a-listview-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Select All  checkbox is out of your list component.
You do not need to maintain the map as your maintaining now.

> Move your logic to SelectAll setOnCheckedChangeListener put of
>   getView() from adapter. And it will only calling
>   notifyDatasetChanged(), not a single line more than this.
>
> So first of all you just need to make sure on
>   setOnCheckedChangeListener for selectAll call notifyDatasetChanged for
>   listview, so all list checkbox components get modified .
>
> In getView method of listview just add check while setting checkbox
>   for individual item i.e. if(selectAll.isChecked()) then mark this
>   checkbox as setSelected(true) otherwise false.
>
> The last one on setOnCheckedChangeListener for particular list item
>   checkbox add the same check as above i.e. if(selectAll.isChecked())
>   but just set SelectAllCheckbox to false.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: So I edited as per your suggestions. Current problem is that when I unselect any one of the listview checkbox(after selecting header checkbox) the listview checkbox gets unselected but not the header checkbox @MobileEvangelist

Comment: Not working. I added header checkbox onchangelistener in Activity and only kept adapter.notifyDatasetChanged. And in listview checkbox chnagelistener `if(_selectall.isChecked()){
                    _selectall.setChecked(false);
                }else{
                    _selectall.setChecked(true);
                }`

Comment: have you added  if(_selectall.isChecked()){
            cBuy.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            cBuy.setChecked(false);
        } right after findviewById and setTag part in getView()..?

Comment: Yes. It would be better if you show me some code so that I can match